# What can we do to stem the tide of Wordpress questions?

Tags: discussion, wordpress-se

It's frustrating to see so many questions on SO about Wordpress.  Yes, you can write PHP code for your Wordpress plugins, but I'm talking about the questions like "I get this undefined variable error when I installed a plugin, now what?"

Comment: Do you have a bucket of tar and a poundage of feathers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Send 'em to the [Wordpress Answers beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1500/wordpress-answers).  They actually need more questions according to the site stats.